# Extending AppCompatActivity crashes the app

Tags: android, appcompatactivity, android-appcompat

I'm creating a simple app to test `AppCompat`, when i extend `AppCompatActivity` the app crashes, and when i run the app without `AppCompat` (extending `android.app.Activity` and everything remains the same),

`MainActivity extends Activity` - works
`MainActivity extends AppCompat Activity` - crashes

Testing on `android 4.4`

LogCat:

```
------------------------------------------------

05-01 23:03:44.916 E/dalvikvm(23031): heapsize Dalvik_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_nativeMinimumHeapSize 0
05-01 23:03:44.916 E/dalvikvm(23031): heapsize Dalvik_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_nativeMinimumHeapSize 15301176
05-01 23:03:44.966 E/dalvikvm(23031): Could not find class 'android.arch.core.internal.FastSafeIterableMap', referenced from method android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.<init>
05-01 23:03:44.986 E/AndroidRuntime(23031): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 23:03:44.986 E/AndroidRuntime(23031): Process: com.android.xDrawer, PID: 23031
05-01 23:03:44.986 E/AndroidRuntime(23031): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.arch.core.internal.FastSafeIterableMap
05-01 23:03:44.986 E/AndroidRuntime(23031):     at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.<init>(LifecycleRegistry.java:59)
05-01 23:03:44.986 E/AndroidRuntime(23031):     at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.<init>(SupportActivity.java:47)
05-01 23:03:44.986 E/AndroidRuntime(23031):     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.<init>(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:28)
05-01 23:03:44.986 E/AndroidRuntime(23031):     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.<init>(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:34)
05-01 23:03:44.986 E/AndroidRuntime(23031):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:68)
05-01 23:03:44.986 E/AndroidRuntime(23031):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.<init>(AppCompatActivity.java:61)
05-01 23:03:44.986 E/AndroidRuntime(23031):     at com.android.xDrawer.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:49)
05-01 23:03:44.986 E/AndroidRuntime(23031):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-01 23:03:44.986 E/AndroidRuntime(23031):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)

-----------------------------------------
```

Adding

```
 vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

In app's gradls didn't solve the problem

Update:

Full gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
              useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
}
```

Activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

   <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Styles:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: can you disable instant run? `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> uncheck "Enable Instant Run"` and try again?

Comment: Am not using Android Studio nor Eclipse, am using AIDE for android OS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved, the problem was that i had `android SDK 21` (android.jar) with `appcompat 27.1.1`, tried android SDK `24,25,26,27` with `appcompat 27.1.1` but still no luck, then tried `android SDK 25` with `appcompat 25.0.0` and it worked like a charm.
Hope this may help anyone with same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you use Proguard? If so, you can customise your Proguard rule config like below:

```
-keep class android.arch.** { *; }
```

Or turn it off completely:

```
debug {
    minifyEnabled false
    useProguard false
}
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: Tried both but still not working  and giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem: app crashed when starting Activity that extends AppCompatActivity.

Solving:

Base application theme:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/windows_background</item>
    </style>
```

I added the theme:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

And apply this theme in AndroidManifest.xml for Activity that extends AppCompatActivity:

```
    <activity android:name=".LoadGameActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:label="@string/label_LoadGameActivity"></activity>
```